# Perl: composing regex thru interpolation when subexpr has capture

Tags: regex, perl, assertions

I am newbie with Perl, but I was wondering what happens if I create a regex variable with captures, or even other kinds of side-effects such as code assertions, and then use interpolation to insert this regex into a larger regex composition, and then repeat this process again?

Is it a mess or even possible to control what the final composition really does in terms of side-effect behavior?  Is there documentation on this?

Comment: Welcome to Perl! Can you give an example of what you mean in short code snippet? I think I might know what you're asking, but it might be better without my assumptions.

Comment: If you're wondering, go ahead and try it. Learning through trial and error is a lot better than having someone hand you the answer.

Comment: As far as captures go, if you use named captures (rather than numbered) and you don't have any name collisions, then that should probabaly work in a general and highly disclaimed sense of should.

Comment: I'm still learning Perl, so I cannot provide a code snippet.  I assume that named capture without collisions is probably the only way to go with this in terms of capture, but I was wondering what kinds of things to watch out for with code assertions that are found in the interpolated regex.

Comment: Even a short 3 liner with a `qr{...}` showing the regex or two you want to create being inserted into a 3rd would help give us an idea of what you want. It doesn't have to work.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org) on this, and it comes with Perl. :)

First, interpolation happens before Perl processes the characters for the pattern. [Understand the order of operations in double quoted contexts](http://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/blog/1496). Any special characters inside the interpolated string are still special.

To answer your question, you just have to try it.

```
use v5.10;

my $start = qr/(Buster|Mimi)/;  
say "Starting regex --> $start";

my $middle = qr/My (cat is $start)/i;   
say "Middle regex --> $middle";

my $end = qr/Find \s+ "$middle"/x;  
say "End regex --> $end";
```

This shows that each regex gets embedded in the larger one, preserving its options.

```
Starting regex --> (?^:(Buster|Mimi))
Middle regex --> (?^i:My (cat is (?^:(Buster|Mimi))))
End regex --> (?^x:Find \s+ "(?^i:My (cat is (?^:(Buster|Mimi))))")
```

The rules for captures are the same at each level. They are determined by the order of the opening capturing parenthesis. Perl doesn't make you keep track of any sort of nesting or "who got there first". If you don't want to track the numbered captured variables, you can use a named capture.

Answer (score -1):

You mean like this?

```
my $name = "bob";
while ($name_from_file = <STDIN>) {
   chomp $name_from_file;
   if ($name_from_file =~ /^$name\n/i)
   print "I got something for $name!\n";
}
```

Yup, you can.

However, a better way is to use `qr` to help build the regular expression:

```
my $re_name = qr(^) . qr(bob) . qr(\s);
while ($name_from_file = <STDIN>) {
   chomp $name_from_file;
   if ($name_from_file =~ /$re_name/i)
   print "I got something for $name!\n";
}
```

This way, your regular expression can more easily interpolate your variable.